# Modify a PictureBox image from the resource folder at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some picture box controls created, and on the project, a resource folder. From this resource folder, the picture box controls have a default image.
How can I modify, ON-RUNTIME, the image of a picture box control?

What I've done so far is this:

```
PictureBox photo1 = new PictureBox();
photo1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"path");
```

But, the problem I've encountered, is, If I would set up the path of the picture box control, It should be the same for all users that will use my application, on different machines.

How can I do to select the images directly from my resource folder?

Comment: is the image embedded as a resource?

Comment: I don't properly understand the question. In the Solution Explorer, I have Resource Folder, and there are the images used in project. And, I want, on RUN TIME, related to the IF statement, to change a image with another... Hope you understand what I want to say..

Comment: You can have resources in your project, but I think you are using that term for a sub-directory of your executable.  It's a bit confusing.

Comment: Yes @PalleDue. I've found the solution on that topic. Thank you so much all of you, especially you =)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Forms, resources (also including images), are typically accessed through the dynamically generated `Resources` class within your projects `Properties` namespace via static properties.

We can add resources by putting the files into the `Resources` folder within our project and by adding them to the `Properties\Resources.resx` file using the resource file editor integrated in Visual Studio. The resources get compiled into the assembly.

Afterwards, we can access the images, e.g., with `<default-namespace>.Properties.Resources.MyImage1` (by default, the name of the property is derived from the file name).

```
PictureBox photo1 = new PictureBox();
photo1.Image = <default-namespace>.Properties.Resources.MyImage1;
```